# Present Value function

Tags: javascript, excel, math

I have the following formula in Excel:

```
=-PV(9.38%, 3(yrs), £300)
```

and this comes to £754 which is correct.

I need to know how these numbers are used to produce 754, I need the mathematical formula from which I will then be able to replicate it in JavaScript.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

PV stands for Present Value - here's one implementation in JavaScript:

http://www.mohaniyer.com/old/pvcode.htm

Or [search for others](https://www.google.com/search?q=javascript+present+value).

The math for `pv(rate, per, pmt)` is

```
SUM(n = 1 to per) of pmt/((1+rate)^n)
= 300/(1+.0938)^1 + 300/(1+.0938)^2 + 300/(1+.0938)^3
= 274.27 + 250.75 + 229.25 = 754.28
```

More info [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Present_value)

Comment: I don't need the code, I need to figure out the mathematical formula which gives £754 as a result, thanks

Answer (score 0):

Its a basic present value formula from basic financial theory.

Why wouldn't you Google it at a place like :

http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel-help/pv-HP005209225.aspx

> PV
>
> Show AllShow All Returns the present value of an investment. The
>   present value is the total amount that a series of future payments is
>   worth now. For example, when you borrow money, the loan amount is the
>   present value to the lender.
>
> Syntax
>
> PV(rate,nper,pmt,fv,type)
>
> Rate     is the interest rate per period. For example, if you obtain
>   an automobile loan at a 10 percent annual interest rate and make
>   monthly payments, your interest rate per month is 10%/12, or 0.83%.
>   You would enter 10%/12, or 0.83%, or 0.0083, into the formula as the
>   rate.
>
> Nper     is the total number of payment periods in an annuity. For
>   example, if you get a four-year car loan and make monthly payments,
>   your loan has 4*12 (or 48) periods. You would enter 48 into the
>   formula for nper.
>
> Pmt     is the payment made each period and cannot change over the
>   life of the annuity. Typically, pmt includes principal and interest
>   but no other fees or taxes. For example, the monthly payments on a
>   $10,000, four-year car loan at 12 percent are $263.33. You would enter
>   -263.33 into the formula as the pmt. If pmt is omitted, you must include the fv argument.
>
> Fv     is the future value, or a cash balance you want to attain after
>   the last payment is made. If fv is omitted, it is assumed to be 0 (the
>   future value of a loan, for example, is 0). For example, if you want
>   to save $50,000 to pay for a special project in 18 years, then $50,000
>   is the future value. You could then make a conservative guess at an
>   interest rate and determine how much you must save each month. If fv
>   is omitted, you must include the pmt argument.

Comment: the page link not found